# WinRT MediaElement Source

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, mediaelement

I am attempting to have multiple  MediaElements on a page and have each element rotate videos every 10-20 seconds.  The MediaElements are all started at the same time, so they play fine until I try to change the sources.  When I am changing the sources (via DispatchTimer), only one video is able to play at a time.  Whichever MediaElement.Source is set last is the one that is left able to play.

As far as I can tell, no errors/exceptions are occurring.  Each timer is ticking correctly and and successfully setting each corresponding MediaElement.Source.

Why are the MediaElements not playing, when another MediaElement has it's source set?

Comment: Posting your ode would help...

Comment: As @makc suggested, posting your code (or something similar) in this case is almost a necessity. Quick question though: is it the same media element being played in each case? Like, is it the same Uri or different for each element? Lastly, are you using `MediaElement.Source =` or `MediaElement.SetSource`?